# Why would product not be indexed?

Tags: configurable-product, frontend, indexing, status, flat

I have a configurable product which is enabled, and visible in catalog, search. It has a child product which is also enabled, and in stock. But the product is not visible on the frontend.

I have found that this is because it is not in the flat table. Not does it appear in any of the index tables. What could cause a product it be ignored by magento like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `Websites` tab in the admin edit form. Maybe it's not assigned to any websites. If it's not. Then assign it and re-index everything.

Answer (score 2):

A few reasons why it would not be in the flat index:

- It is disabled
- It is not in a category
- Its category is not associated with a root category for the current website/view